# How to update web.config on each WFE in a SharePoint server farm?

Tags: sharepoint, web-config

We have a SharePoint farm with multiple WFEs.  A new application requires us to write some custom code to the `web.config` during deployment.  What is the best way modify the the `web.config` file during deployment, ensuring that each WFE in the farm get updated?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you'll be deploying your code via a WSP; if not, using a tool like [WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder) is a great starting place that allows you to get rolling without forcing you to learn all of the intricate details of solution package construction.

You should leverage the **[SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx)** type from within a custom **[SPFeatureReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.aspx)**.  Normally, the **FeatureActivated** method of the **SPFeatureReceiver** would be coded to write the changes out to the web.config files impacted by your activation.  Those same changes would then be retracted in the **FeatureDeactivating** method.

The nice thing about the **SPWebConfigModification** type is that SharePoint takes care of determining which web.config files should be modified -- across servers and across extended web apps.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

As part of your deployment, use the [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification_properties.aspx) class to add/remove entries from web.config. SharePoint will manage updating the WFEs for you if you use this.

A blog post entitled, [Modify the web.config file in SharePoint using SPWebConfigModification](http://blog.crsw.com/2007/09/20/how-to-modify-the-web-config-file-in-sharepoint-using-spwebconfigmodification/), is a great summation of the gotchas involved and contains links to other helpful resources.

Comment: Good link, Alex; lots of useful tips in that one!

Comment: Great link, here's some more (class to add/remove appsetings)

http://sharepointlive.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-add-or-remove-appsettings.html