# SharePoint Deployment web.config entry

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, web-config

I am new to sharepoint. I have to deploy an application from one server to another server (Test Server). Now I am using solution package to deploy the application. I have one problem in Deploying. In the web.config of the application there are entries like appsetting entries, safe control entries, endpoint entries for our own services and lot others. Currently I am doing it manually. Only safe control entries are updated in web.config file through manifest.xml, but I don't know how to update for other entries. Please help me on this problem.

I have one more problem too. I have to make something like click once deployment. How can I do it? Can I deploy the application with changed web.config like an installer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Belong at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

jkpadhi,

If you don't have any programmatic control over your codebase, then Rushyo is correct -- you'd probably have better luck with your questions over on serverfault.  The rest of this answer assumes that you are more of a developer and have access to make code changes.

SharePoint includes the **SPWebConfigModification** type to support the type of web.config changes that you'd like to make, and this type is typically employed during Feature activation and deactivation using a FeatureReceiver.  Refer to this stackoverflow post, as it includes some additional qualifying information and a handful of links from Alex Angas, Colin Dekker, and me:

[How to update web.config on each WFE in a SharePoint server farm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093394/how-to-update-web-config-on-each-wfe-in-a-sharepoint-server-farm)

As for a ClinkOnce-style deployment: I don't think you're going to be able to make things quite that simple for solution package installation.  You can get pretty close, though, with a solution that Lars Fastrup (one of the SharePoint regulars here on stackoverflow) put together and placed out on CodePlex.  His solution allows you to place an installer wrapper around a solution package (WSP), and the installer takes care of things like dependency checking for you.  See http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively have a look at [this tool](http://stsadmwebconfig.codeplex.com/)

It'll allow you to make modifications to web.config through an stsadm command (no code needed). I use it in deploy scripts for my clients.