# Access config file from a VS Sharepoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, web-config, app-config, configuration-files

I want to store some setting in web.config file of the sharepoint web application or in app.config of the workflow itself. But i don't know how to access neither of these files and i don't know how to handle the data inside them. Please, give some advise, how to do this or where to read about doing this.

Any information is helpful.
Alexandr.

Comment: @Alexandr, 10 questions and 0 accepted, you should accept / up vote an answer if it is helpfull. This will also improve your chances of getting an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexandr, you will need to use the SPWebConfigModification class from the Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration namespace to make any modifications to your web application's web.config file. It's no easy task but I've done it several times before. If you'd like more detailed instructions please let me know.

EDIT: I'll stop being lazy now and give you some links to get you started. Here ya go!

[How to update web.config on each WFE in a SharePoint server farm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093394/how-to-update-web-config-on-each-wfe-in-a-sharepoint-server-farm)

http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/?p=459

http://www.crsw.com/mark/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=32

http://antonzhi.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!76D1A388C70D6997!108.entry

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/864dd894-c4cb-4815-a3de-8717d38da5ae