# sharepoint workflow config file

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I'm developing sharepoint workflow inside which I call custom web service. Where can I put the configuration file (section), so I can change the url in the future for the web service? With the default one is working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this question [Access config file from a VS Sharepoint Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592574/access-config-file-from-a-vs-sharepoint-workflow) which has been already answered

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an association form for your workflow. That has worked pretty well for me.